# Create a remote branch on a repository based on an existing local branch

Tags: git

I want to push my *origin master* to another remote repository and to a specific branch on this remote repository. The thing is, this branch doesn't exist yet on the remote repository. How can create a remote branch on this repository ?

Basically, I want to do something like `git push origin master:myRemote newBranchToCreate` where *myRemote* was already added by `git remote add myRemote {remoteUrl}` and where *newBranchToCreate* doesn't exist yet but should be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Push Checked-Out Master Branch

If you just want to push your current master branch to a remote, the syntax is simple. For example:

```
# Make sure you're current with origin.
git checkout master
git pull

# Create a new remote, then push the current branch
# to a new branch on that new remote.
git add myNewRemote <url>
git push myNewRemote master:someNewBranch
```

### Push Upstream *Origin/Master*

If you want to push what's in your current upstream branch rather than your checked-out local master branch, you can use the hidden *origin/master* branch and a fully-qualified refspec on the new remote. To push a non-current branch to a differently-named branch on the new remote:

```
# Make sure you have the latest version of origin/master
# in your repository.
git fetch --all

# Create the new remote and push origin/master
# to an arbitrary branch on that remote.
git add myNewRemote <url>
git push myNewRemote origin/master:refs/remotes/NewRemote/someNewBranch
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ! When I try your command I get "The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref"

Comment: @JérômeSengel Sometimes Git needs a more [fully-qualified refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec). I've updated my answer and tested it on my system with Git v2.7.1. It should work now as described.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "git push myRemote master:newBranchToCreate"

Answer (score 1):

> I want to push my origin master to another remote repository and to a specific branch on this remote repository

In order to do it you must create a new branch and then push it. (assuming you are using git version >2.0.

#### Why?

Since in git version 2.0 the mechanism of pull and push was updaed

> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional ***matching*** semantics so far (all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there).  In Git 2.0, the default is now the ***simple*** semantics,
>   which pushes:
>
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, and only
>     when the current branch is set to integrate with that remote
>     branch, if you are pushing to the same remote as you fetch from; or
> - only the current branch to the branch with the same name, if you
>     are pushing to a remote that is not where you usually fetch from.
>
> You can use the configuration variable `push.default` to change
>   this.  If you are an old-timer who wants to keep using the
>   `matching` semantics, you can set the variable to `matching`, for
>   example.  Read the documentation for other possibilities.

---

#### What to do?

```
# update your local repository
git fetch --all --prune

# checkout the desired branch you want to start from 
git checkout <branch_name>

# grab the last changes into the branch
git pull origin <branch name>

# now create the new branch name you want to push
git checkout -b <new branch>

# Now you can push the branch with the new name to your remote.
# The explantion why is in the previous section
```

Answer (score 0):

[Do this with ordinary push.  Git supplies a lot of defaults for the usual cases, but the fundamental push operation is a repository url or path, a local commit<sup>1</sup>, and a remote refname](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).  Anything you don't supply, git looks up for you.

You can test this stuff out with *any* repository.  Any commit. Any refname.

```
git init ../fun
git push ../fun HEAD:refs/heads/funfunfun
```

Everything else is just a matter of setting up git's machinery to supply defaults for you.  Want a handy name to refer to the other repository in case it changes or so you can associate some defaults and other notes with it? Set up a "remote".  And so forth.

[git push docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

[git remote docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote).

[git config docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

---

**Edit**: to do specifically

> Basically, I want to do something like `git push origin master:myRemote newBranchToCreate`

what you describe, if I'm interpreting it correctly the command would be

```
git push myRemote refs/remotes/origin/master:refs/heads/newBranchToCreate
```

and you could probably get by with `origin/master` for `refs/remotes/origin/master` because if a refname doesn't exist, git will check whether some likely-looking shortcuts are valid, but remember that everything short of the full-spell command is relying on heuristics hunting through your repo trying to identify what you probably meant.  There's limits on that.

---

<sup><sup><sup>1</sup>it doesn't have to be a commit.</sup></sup>